# antd - localize weekdays in DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

I try to change days of the week in datepicker to other language than english without multiple lines of strange declarations. There are a few ways mentioned everywhere (e.g. by adding `moment/locale` import), but still all I've got are polish placeholder in input and polish "Today" button below calendar, but both shortcut of current month as well as days of the week are still in english.

I even tested it on react playground using versions below, same errors appear:

`antd` - newest 5.1.2, but I know it behaves the same in v4 too

`moment` - newest (2.29.4)

Here is the link and the whole code:
https://playcode.io/1051677

```
import React from 'react';

import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import 'moment/locale/pl';
import moment from 'moment';
import locale from 'antd/es/date-picker/locale/pl_PL';

export const App = () => {
 
 moment.locale('pl');

  return (
      <DatePicker
        locale={locale}
      />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the locale for `dayjs`. See [Replace Day.js locale](https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#replace-dayjs-locale),

> Replace moment.js locale with day.js locale:

```
-   import moment from 'moment';
+   import dayjs from 'dayjs';
-   import 'moment/locale/zh-cn';
+   import 'dayjs/locale/zh-cn';
-   moment.locale('zh-cn');
+   dayjs.locale('zh-cn');
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import 'dayjs/locale/pl';
import locale from 'antd/es/date-picker/locale/pl_PL';

dayjs.locale('pl');

export const App = () => {
  return (
      <DatePicker
        locale={locale}
      />
  );
}
```

Output:

[image]